# Simple XML Schema to XSD validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I tried to figure out the solution to this problem, but can't seem to find it.
This is just a simple XSD, XML file format.
The error I keep getting is: ERROR: Element 'contact': This element is not expected.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"si:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="address.xsd">
     <contact>
        <name>Hana Song</name>
        <phone>82-51-120</phone>
        <street>1001 Jungang-daero, Yeonje-gu</street>
        <city>Busan</city>
        <origin>Republic of Korea, South Korea</origin>
        <zip>47545</zip>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>Genji Shimada</name>
        <phone>949-955-1380</phone>
        <street>1 Blizzard Way</street>
        <city>Irvine</city>
        <origin>CA, USA</origin>
        <zip>92618</zip>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>Jesse McCree</name>
        <phone>800-777-2489</phone>
        <street>201 W. Marcy St.</street>
        <city>Santa Fe</city>
        <origin>NM, USA</origin>
        <zip>87501</zip>
    </contact>
</address>
```

XSD File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--definition of simple elements -->

    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="origin" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string"/>

<!--definition of attributes elements -->

<!--definition of complex elements-->
    <xs:element name="address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="contact"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="contact">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="phone"/>
        <xs:element ref="street"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="origin"/>
        <xs:element ref="zip"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple `contact` elements in your XML, but Schema allows only one, because there are attributes:

`minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`. By default they are equal 1.

So... change your schema as:

```
<!--definition of complex elements-->
<xs:element name="address">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="contact" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

P.S. Keep in mind minOccurs="1" requires at least one element be there. If no contacts at all can be there, then make `minOccurs="0"`.

Also maxOccurs="unbounded" is not recommended, due to possibility of "infinite XML attack".
It is better to set it to some large, but real maxValue. as example `maxOccurs="1000"`.

Comment: Your answered helped be understand it better. Thank you!

Comment: (Also maxOccurs="unbounded" is not recommended, due to possibility of "infinite XML attack). I disagree strongly with that advice. Firstly, large finite values of maxOccurs (or minOccurs) can be extremely expensive on some processors, itself a potential DDoS attack. Secondly, a schema that doesn't allow infinite values somewhere would be very cumbersome indeed. 3rd, if you want to limit the size of incoming XML documents, there are much better ways of doing it: this is not a job for XML Schema.

Comment: I will not argue... but I saw such attacks. Of course there are a lot of  better ways and it is not a job for XML Schema... but IMHO it can be last line of defense when other options out of your control and somebody, somewhere did not do his job properly... (quite often situation in large organizations).